# How to store UTM parameters in a cookie using google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Hi I'm running Facebook ads with visitors landing on a calendly booking page(embedded on my website) with UTM parameters in the URL.

When they book in they are redirected to another page which is where the issue happens. Because of the nature of calendly with how I'm having to use the redirect it removes all of the utm parameters which I need on the page they land on to send to google analytics.

I am very new an inexpereinced with javascript so I've been asking for the assistance of chatgpt to help me write the scripts.

Calendly said a good option would be to have a cookie that stores all of the utm parameters which is what my code is for and is triggered using google tag manager (GTM).

The tag I have created is firing correctly however I don't see any cookies or console log messages in the console window:

```
<script>
      console.log("Setting cookie: FbAdUTMCookie");  
function getQueryParam(url, param) {

  var queryString = url.split('?')[1];
  if (!queryString) return null;

  var params = queryString.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var keyValue = params[i].split('=');
    if (keyValue[0] === param) {
      return decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

function storeUtmParameters() {
  var utmParams = ['utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_content', 'ad_id', 'adset_id', 'campaign_id', 'site_source_name', 'adset_name'];
  var eventData = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < utmParams.length; i++) {
    var paramValue = getQueryParam(window.location.href, utmParams[i]);
    if (paramValue) {
      eventData[utmParams[i]] = paramValue;
    }
  }

  if (Object.keys(eventData).length > 0) {
    console.log("Setting cookie: FbAdUTMCookie");
    setCookie('FbAdUTMCookie', JSON.stringify(eventData), 30); // Store cookie for 30 days
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
      console.log("Setting cookie: FbAdUTMCookie");  
function getQueryParam(url, param) {

  var queryString = url.split('?')[1];
  if (!queryString) return null;

  var params = queryString.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var keyValue = params[i].split('=');
    if (keyValue[0] === param) {
      return decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

function storeUtmParameters() {
  var utmParams = ['utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_content', 'ad_id', 'adset_id', 'campaign_id', 'site_source_name', 'adset_name'];
  var eventData = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < utmParams.length; i++) {
    var paramValue = getQueryParam(window.location.href, utmParams[i]);
    if (paramValue) {
      eventData[utmParams[i]] = paramValue;
    }
  }

  if (Object.keys(eventData).length > 0) {
    console.log("Setting cookie: FbAdUTMCookie");
    setCookie('FbAdUTMCookie', JSON.stringify(eventData), 30); // Store cookie for 30 days
  }
}

// Here
storeUtmParameters();

</script>
```

Looks like you only missed to call the function `storeUtmParameters` which you already declared.

But from this code, there are something missing. You will store every traffic has utm on it. The following might be disappeared.

1. Google Ads: enable auto-tagging.
   This will make the url like : ?gclid=xxxxxx => usually GA will show `google/cpc`
2. FB also have the feature, will make the url like ?fbclid=xxxxx
3. Organic traffic will not show. Because these traffic are recognized by referral is google.com or bing.com (The search engine domain)

Comment: Thank you very much I asked chat gpt about that line originally whether it was needed to call the function and it told me no because GTM will call it, but then it kept contradicting itself. Adding that line worked.

Can you please elaborate what you mean by how something may disappear, the source the traffic is coming from is Facebook ads so do I need to add ?fbclid=xxxxx somewhere if so where?

Comment: I remembered there is some github repository already did this part. I will add it here if I fount that. 
Basically the concept is there are some paid traffic are not brining the utm_source and utm_medium on the url. If you want to get the number, you will need to modify the code.